# Will photons still be entangled in polarisation, when I know its polarisation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, conventions, crystals, non-linear-optics

Imagine if i have a KDP crystal (the property of the KDP crystal is, the polarisation of singnal and idler photons that come out by parametric down conversion is orthogonal to pump photon, and both the signal and idler photons share same polarisation) and i shine a +45° polarised light on to the crystal, then i know that the out coming photons must have -45° polarisation, the -45° polarisation is considered to be in superposition of linear and horizontal polarisation, so both the signal and idler photons are in superposition of linear and horizontal polarisation as they are -45° polarised, but they are entangled, means if i measure the polarisation of signal photon in vertical axis, and if i get the signal photon to be vertically polarised, then the idler photon will also be in vertically polarised state as they both are entangled right ?

Comment: What experiment will you perform to determine this?

Comment: Well, i don't perform any experiment i just got this question in my head.

Comment: I request you to try answering it if you know.

Comment: Quantum theory only predicts the results of experiments.

Comment: Okay, but what quantum mechanics predicts here, will the photons will be in the superposition of linear and horizontal axis??

Comment: You haven't yet defined what you mean by stating the experiment you'll do to find out.

Comment: If you put a double slit apparatus with orthogonal polarisers on the slits and send the one of the entangled photons through it if it makes interference it is in superposition, non interference means non superposition.

Comment: Sir, please try answering it.

Comment: You do not understand polarizers. If the photon is diagonally polarized it has a 50% chance of going through a vertical polarizer. If you detect one after the vertical polarizer you still cannot guarantee that the other entangled photon will pass its vertical polarizer. Each photon is itself and will interact with polarizers independently. As to answer your question, second photon still has only 50% probability of passing through a vertical polarizer. If you stop thinking about particles and think about waves all your problems disappear.

Answer (score 2):

When you put your laser on the 45 degree polarizer half of the photons will be (reflected or absorbed) and half will be transmitted.  The transmitted photons are just regular photons as far as the crystal is concerned.

The crystal will produce pairs of opposite polarization (i.e. entangled). The crystal does not care about the polarization of the incoming photon .... it will continue to produce pairs that are oppositely polarized.

Comment: But the KDP crystal produce particles with same polarisation unlike BBO crystal, means here if we measure the polarisation of one photon by either a vertical or horizontal polariser means we will know what polarisation the other photon has right, even though when you know the photons are -45° polarised ?

Comment: @MeruguArunKumar OK yes KPD has same polarizations emissions .... BUT it does not care about incoming photon.  The incoming photon is probably most efficiently absorbed at certain direction (and maybe polarization) to the crystal axi but once the photon is absorbed emission is independent.

Comment: But the outgoing photons from a KDP crystal are orthogonally polarised to the incoming photons right?

Comment: I found this on the web: https://www.inradoptics.com/pdfs/KDP_KD*P_DataSheet.pdf  But I am not sure that the outgoing beam is orthogonal to incoming .... it is possible that only absorption is important and that can happen at many incoming angles.